# Is there a difference between these two syntaxes for fat arrow functions, or are they functionally identical?

Tags: angular, typescript

In Angular 6 / Typescript code samples I've seen fat arrow functions called with the following two syntaxes.  Is there some difference between them, or are they functionally identical?

```
blah.then(param => {
    // do something with param
});

blah.then((param) => {
    // do something with param
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are identical in context of JavaScript -- when there's only one argument in the list of arguments in a fat-arrow function, you do not need the wrapping parenthesis.

```
foo => foo // ok
(foo) => foo // ok
```

---

There's a slight difference with TypeScript, though. In order to define a type for a parameter, even when there's only a single argument, you still need the parenthesis:

```
(foo: string) => foo // ok
foo: string => foo // syntax error
```

---

Note that this has nothing to do with Angular, it's just JavaScript and TypeScript.

Also, you've said "fat arrow functions *called*"; however, the examples you've shown doesn't show function call (invocation) -- instead, it shows function *expression*.